# Analytic function with constant imaginary part

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

While learning some consequences of the Cauchy-Riemann theorem. we learned that

> An analytic function with constant imaginary (or real) part is constant.

and in addition,

> Sum of analytic functions is analytic.

Given the second proposition, I understand that the function $f(x+iy)=x+2i$ is analytic. On the other hand, from the first proposition, it must be constant, but it is not (it depends on $x$, which is not a constant.

How can this contradiction be settled? What am I getting wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: The function $f(x+iy) = x + 2i$ is *not* analytic!  That is because the function $x+iy \mapsto x$ is not analytic.  Why did you think it is?  Try computing the complex derivative of the real part function (or the imaginary part function).  Don't confuse real-analytic and complex-analytic functions.  The CR equations are related to complex-analytic functions.

Comment: @KCd: thank you! I completely missed it unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you considered here is $x+2i$. Now, your logic is that the function $``x"$ is analytic and the function $``2i"$ is analytic (although constant). Now, you argument is that sum of two analytic function is constant.

What gone wrong here is the assumption that your first function $``x"$ is analytic. The function $g(x+iy)=x$ is not analytic at all, since its imaginary part is zero, i.e., constant. By your first result, if $g$ has to be analytic, then it must be constant, as its imaginary part is constant. However, g is clearly not a constant function.